# Transferring Django project from Mac to Ubuntu EC2 Instance

Tags: macos, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I am new webservers...and...

I am working on a django project that is ready to go up and I was wondering how to transfer files from my local machine to the EC2 server? I am currently running an Ubuntu instance if that makes any difference.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply upload your files by using `scp` (ssh cp), like this

```
scp your_file ubuntu@[your_server_address]:~/target_path
```

And what's more, you can try `rsync`.

Answer (score 1):

You might try a tool like [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) or [cyberduck](http://cyberduck.ch/).